# Css : margin-left value check in jquery

Tags: jquery

I tried to check the margin-left.But it does not work..Thanks in advance

```
 if( $car1.css("margin-left") == "1060px") {
   $("#result").html("Car One Won The Race!!");     
 }
```

Comment: What exactly does `$car1.css("margin-left")` return? Please add some context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `.css("margin-left")` to `.css("marginLeft")`.

Like This :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($car1.css("marginLeft") == "1060px")

        $("#result").html("Car One Won The Race!!"); 

})
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                margin-left: 1060px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div>I am div, and margin_left 1060px</div>
        <p id="result"></p>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $car1 = $("div");
            if ($car1.css("marginLeft") == "1060px")

                $("#result").html("Car One Won The Race!!"); 

        })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```